Enable text selection on changed lines on VS Code Open Changes editor tab
I can select text on lines with green background, but I can't select text from the red background lines, when I click on those lines, a prompt opens as you can see in the picture. How can I turn the prompt off so I can select text on lines?
The side-by-side view doesn't have this issue. The prompt appears on single view when your workspace is limited, which is annoying.


This is the subject of an open issue ticket: Cannot select text from deleted lines diff view #8226. I am not aware of any workarounds except to switch to the side-by-side view (run Compare: Toggle Inline View in the command palette). I suggest that you give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it. You can also subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump".
